# How to escape double quote for Ruby inside of XML

Tags: ruby, xml

Although I know that I can use `&quote`, I was wondering if there was a less blunt and long way, such as `\"`, or the like.
Here is an example of the XML:

```
<root name="test" type="Node" action="{puts :ROOT.to_s}">
    <leaf type="Node" decider="{print :VAL1.to_s; gets.chomp.to_i}" action="{puts :ONE.to_s}" />
    <leaf type="Node" decider="{print :VAL2.to_s; gets.chomp.to_i}" action="{puts :TWO.to_s}" />
    <branch type="Node" decider="{100}" action="{}">
        <leaf type="LikelihoodNode" decider="{100}" action="{puts :HI.to_s}" arg="0"/>
    </branch>
</root>
```

The attributes that need this are `decider` and `action`. Right now the embedded code is using a little :sym.to_s hack, but that is not a solution.

NOTE: Although the `action` attribute is only a block in brackets, the processing code pre-pends the `lambda`.

Comment: I am embedding Ruby code in the XML. The code is not doable if I have to type `&quote` every time I want a string.

Comment: You are embedding Ruby code inside an XML attribute? And you are using REXML to generate the document? What is your desired XML output?

Comment: Ever heard of [CDATA](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/CData.html)?

Comment: Not to generate the output, but to read a hand written XML document.

Comment: I was also hoping to be able to embed the code in a less verbose way, a simpler syntax equal to CDATA might be nice, if such a thing exists. Might REXML have an XML escape method?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh You still need to provide more details. What does the XML that you are hand-authoring look like? Specifically, is the Ruby code in an attribute (if so, why?) or as a text node (where you could use a CDATA)? It sounds like REXML and Ruby are completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I would suggest using a DSL or other (e.g. YAML) markup for your content, and then a super-simple script to convert it to XML with proper encoding of the data. Hand-authoring XML is error-prone, especially when doing something as ugly as this. (This doesn't directly answer your question, so I'm posting as a comment, not answer.)

Comment: XML seems to be the simplest thing here, and this is a small utility for me, so I am content to use XML with a little help from gedit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A double quote inside an XML attribute is written as `&quote;` (or `&#34;` or `&#x22;`). You'll have similar issues with single quotes too so you can't use those. However, you can use `%` as-is in an XML attribute so `%|...|`, `%Q|...|`, and `%q|...|` are available and they're as easy to read and type as quotes:

```
<root name="test" type="Node" action="{puts %|ROOT|}">
    <leaf type="Node" decider="{print %|VAL1|; gets.chomp.to_i}" action="{puts %|ONE|}" />
    <!-- ... -->
</root>
```

Choose whichever delimiters you find the easiest to type and read.

You can also use single quotes for your attributes in XML so you can have:

```
<leaf type='Node' decider='{print "VAL1"; gets.chomp.to_i}' ...
```

But then you'd have to use `&apos;` inside the attribute if you needed to include a single quote.

Alternatively, you could switch to elements instead of attributes:

```
<leaf type="Node">
    <decider><![CDATA[
        print "VAL1"
        gets.chomp.to_i
    ]]></decider>
    <action><![CDATA[
        puts "ONE"
    ]]></decider>
</leaf>
```

but that's a bit verbose, ugly, and not as easy to work with as attributes (IMHO).

Comment: You might also note that single quotes are legal XML attribute delimiters as well as Ruby string delimiters (if interpolation is not needed), if that makes things simple enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the first approach better. This is what I was looking for, so I am going to accept the answer. Considering that the script that parses this can also get the code from a file, this will be perfect.

Comment: @Phrogz: But then you might run into the `'` vs `&apos;` problem, no? I tend to ditch single and double quotes at the drop of a hat, I have more important things to worry about (such as how much snow fell last night) than quoting and escaping issues. I'll add a note about the single quotes for completeness though.

Comment: @Linux: I tend to switch to %-quoting as soon as things get even moderately complicated so I'd probably go with `action="{puts %|ROOT|}"` and such too.

Comment: That's what I did. I tried it last night, and it worked. My small tool is perfect now. Thanks!